# Why do my NVIDIA drivers stop supporting OpenCL a few days after reinstalling?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda, opencl

For the longest time, I could not get NVIDIA OpenCL or CUDA to work on my Optimus enabled laptop. I finally got it working by purging all `nvidia` packages with `sudo apt-get --purge remove '*nvidia*'` and reinstalling the driver metapackage with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470` then rebooting.

OpenCL worked just fine for a few days and my card showed up when I ran `clinfo`. Then, it stopped working and does not show up in clinfo. When I tried purging and reinstalling, it worked for a few days again and then stopped a few days later again. What could be the issue?